# Inspect method active_queues failed - celery flower

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I brought together different components of a ML application using celery flower & worker, Fast API, redis and RabbitMQ into docker-compose, but I seem to be getting an error with the celery_flower component that affects any calls made to it. Unfortunately can't share the images of the ML and celery_flower services, but any inputs on possible bugs in my docker-compose file would be very helpful.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: custom-image
    container_name: web_app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 14565:14565
    depends_on:
      - amqp
      - celery_worker
      - redis
  amqp:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    container_name: rabbit_mq_test
    ports:
      - 4369:4369
      - 5672:5672
      - 25672:25672
      - 15672:15672
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis_container
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  celery_worker:
    image: custom-image
    working_dir: /webapp/endpoints/contents/
    container_name: celery_worker
    command: /opt/conda/envs/webapp/bin/celery -A router.celery_app worker --loglevel=info -P threads
    depends_on:
      - amqp
      - redis

  celery_flower:
    container_name: celery_flower
    working_dir: /webapp/endpoints/contents/
    image: mher/flower:latest
    command: celery --broker 'amqp://guest:guest@amqp:5672//' --result-backend 'rpc://' flower
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@amqp:5672//
      - FLOWER_PORT=5555
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    depends_on:
      - amqp
      - redis
```

Error logs from celery_flower:

```
celery_flower | [I 221213 19:33:42 command:162] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
celery_flower | [I 221213 19:33:42 command:170] Broker: amqp://guest:**@amqp:5672//
celery_flower | [I 221213 19:33:42 command:171] Registered tasks: 
celery_flower |   ['celery.accumulate',
celery_flower |    'celery.backend_cleanup',
celery_flower |    'celery.chain',
celery_flower |    'celery.chord',
celery_flower |    'celery.chord_unlock',
celery_flower |    'celery.chunks',
celery_flower |    'celery.group',
celery_flower |    'celery.map',
celery_flower |    'celery.starmap']
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:42 command:177] Running without authentication
celery_flower | [I 221213 19:33:48 mixins:225] Connected to amqp://guest:**@amqp:5672//
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method active_queues failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method active failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method scheduled failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method reserved failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method registered failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method revoked failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method conf failed
celery_flower | [W 221213 19:33:49 inspector:42] Inspect method stats failed
```

I cannot spot anything wrong with the celery flower dashboard too which is quite confusing.
[image: Celery flower dashboard]